# Where does everyone get all the alcohol?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

Early in the 2004 *Battlestar Galactica*, Chief Tyrol discovers some of the crew using a homemade still from spare parts to make their own alcohol. He ends up showing them how to fix/improve it.

After that, through the show, we see at least two fully operational bars on the Galactica itself, and asides from rare occasion, there never seems to be a lack of available alcohol (the exceptions being when Tigh has already finished/disposed of his stash).

By the end of the show, the fleet is low on supplies like toothpaste, but the alcohol never seems to stop flowing.

### Is there ever an explanation for where all of this magical alcohol keeps coming from?

Comment: Alcohol simply requires sugar, water, and yeast.  Mankind has proven, again and again and again, that no matter how bad things get, enough food can _always_ be leached out of the supply chain to make alcohol.

Comment: Yes, and there are supply shortages at multiple times through the show - including water and food shortages shortages.

Comment: @phantom42 - And what better way to take your mind off the food and water crisis than with a nice frosty cup of moonshine?

Comment: And the number of people industrious enough to make their own stills to create space-moonshine is unlikely to be enough to keep the fleet swimming in alcohol - especially with Tigh and Starbuck around.

Comment: @phantom42 Alcohol keeps in a way fresh produce doesn't, who's to say the alcohol isn't only made in the good times but doesn't run out during the bad times

Answer (score 6):

Consider the early pioneers in the American frontier in the Eighteenth century.  Alcohol is a good place to store surplus food stuffs.  A very reliable trade good, that is something with alot of value, portable and relatively small.  It seems very likely that among all the civilians there would be quite a few that knew their way around a still.  Over time there would be more supply than at the beginning of the voyage.  As to why you see an easy supply, consider that the cameras followed the elite of the group who would have more to trade in exchange for alcohol.